# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, type found

Tags: python, file-io, typeerror

I'm trying to write a code that will read a file and make some manipulations on it.

the code:

```
def assem(file):
    import myParser
    from myParser import Parser
    import code
    import symboleTable
    from symboleTable import SymboleTable


newFile = "Prog.hack"
output = open(newFile, 'w')
input = open(file, 'r')


prsr=Parser(input)
while prsr.hasMoreCommands():
      str = "BLANK"
      if(parser.commandType() == Parser.C_COMMAND):
      str="111"+code.comp(prsr.comp())+code.dest(prsr.dest())+code.jump(prsr.jump())+"\n"

output.write(str)
prsr.advance()
```

the error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assembler.py", line 11, in <module>
    input = open(file, 'r')
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, type found
```

how i run the program:

```
   python assembler.py Add.asm
```

where Add.asm id the file i want to read, all modules are in the same library, including the .asm file.

Comment: `file` is a built-in type in python, don't use this name for your variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have multiple problems.

Firstly, your indentation is inconsistent. That means that the imports are considered as part of the `assem` function, but nothing else is. Literally the first thing that you have to know about Python is that indentation is significant.

Secondly, you're using a built-in function name, `file`, for the name of your variable. Don't do that.

Thirdly, you don't actually call the `assem` function. But because of your first problem, the first unindented lines are executed on startup. So when the line `input = open(file, 'r')` is reached, `file` still refers to the built-in function, not your variable (which isn't defined at this point).

Finally, although this isn't actually causing your problem, you don't need to do both `import myParser` and `from myParser import Parser`. Pick one.

Comment: Please isolate, concentrate and reply on the issue in question, which is the "TypeError". Other other issues (e.g. indentation) are irrelevant. People expect to find answers on the particular issue, not a paper examination !

Answer (score -1):

> File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 488, in abspath
>       path = _getfullpathname(path) TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, builtin_function_or_method found